# How to change the cursor type when a TableView class was added to a Swing application?

Tags: cursor, javafx, tableview

We can resize column width by dragging the column divider in the table header. This is a built-in feature of the TableView class.

Normally, the cursor will become to east-resize (or west-resize) type with positioning the cursor just to the right of a column header.

However, I found that the cursor is remaining the default type at the same position if I integrate JavaFX into Swing Application. That is adding the TableView to a Scene, and then adding this Scene to a JFXPanel, finally, adding this JFXPanel to the JFrame.

The sample codes are listing below:

```
public class Run extends JFrame {

    Run() {
        setSize(600, 450);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        this.getContentPane().add(fxPanel);
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Scene scene = null;
        try {
            scene = FXMLLoader.load(
                new File("res/fxml_example.fxml").toURI().toURL()
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Run().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

fxml_example.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>

<Scene xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <TableView fx:id="tableView"
               editable="true">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn text="COL1">
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="COL2">
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="COL3">
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="COL4">
            </TableColumn>
            <TableColumn text="COL5">
            </TableColumn>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</Scene>
```

So, are there anyone can advise how to fix these codes; make the cursor can change to east-resize (or west-resize) type when this TableView class was added to a Swing application?